# SQL case when multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 country columns that keep a track of the books in the specific region. For example, EN='Y', GE='N', and so on. I am creating a view and want to add each record in the available country column. So if EN='Y' and GE='Y' it would list them as 'en, ge' in the available country. So far what I have is:

```
case 
   when EN = 'Y' and GE = 'Y' 
      then 'EN, GE' 
   when EN = 'N' and GE = 'Y' 
      then 'GE' 
end as 'available country'
```

This works but I have 4 more columns and might add more and defining each condition feels insufficient.

Is there a better way to concatenate values instead of specifying each one condition?

Comment: I am working on Postgres @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: This sounds like a bad database design. Those columns should be rows representing a one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CONCAT_WS` with `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', CASE WHEN EN = 'Y' THEN 'EN' END,
                      CASE WHEN GE = 'Y' THEN 'GE' END,
                      ...) AS "available country"
FROM yourTable;
```

But a much better table design would be something like this:

```
id | language | val
1  | EN       | Y
1  | GE       | N
```

Using this design, you could simply aggregate by `id` and filter for only those languages which have yes values, e.g. something like this:

```sql
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(language)
FROM yourTable
WHERE val = 'Y'
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the columns into rows (what they should be in the first place), then use `string_agg()` to get the comma separated list:

```
select t.id, f.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    select string_agg(colname, ',') as available_countries
    from (  
      values (en, 'EN'), 
             (ge, 'GE'), 
             (de, 'DE'), 
             (fr, 'FR')
    ) x(flag, colname)
    where flag = 'Y'
  ) as f
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you will have to use CASE WHEN with you current database design. Please check if this works for you.

```
select TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM c1_new||c2_new||c3_new||c4_new) as concat_col
from 
(
    select case when c1 = 'Y' then 'C1,' else null end as c1_new,
           case when c2 = 'Y' then 'C2,' else null end as c2_new,
           case when c3 = 'Y' then 'C3,' else null end as c3_new,
           case when c4 = 'Y' then 'C4'      else null end as c4_new
    from   TABLE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked in PostgreSQL. So if anybody needs Oracle equivalent :

```
SELECT TRIM (
           TRAILING ',' FROM (   DECODE (c1, 'Y', 'c1' || ',', NULL)
                              || DECODE (c2, 'Y', 'c2' || ',', NULL)
                              || DECODE (c3, 'Y', 'c3' || ',', NULL)
                              || DECODE (c4, 'Y', 'c4' || ',', NULL)))
  FROM (SELECT 'Y' c1, 'Y' c2,'N' c3,'Y' c4 FROM DUAL)
```

This query returns :

> c1,c2,c4